# Compile Lua script to 32 bit bytecode on MacOS

Tags: macos, lua, macos-catalina, luac

I am compiling a Lua script into a binary on MacOS Catalina.

```
luac -s -o bin/my-binary.luac src/my-code.lua"
```

However, the application consuming the compiled script runs a 32-bit version of Lua and can't read the bytecode of the 64-bit compiled Lua script. (Error message: bad header in precompiled chunk).

Can I somehow (cross)compile the Lua script on current MacOS to a 32-bit binary?
My alternative would be doing the compilation with Docker but maybe there is an even simpler approach.

Comment: There is a [bytecode converter](https://lua-bytecode.github.io/).  Convert your bytecode (`L4888` -> `L4488`) to change the parameter "Size of C pointer" from 8 to 4

Comment: Or use Lua 5.4 - its bytecode does not depend on the bitness of C pointer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any option for cross-compilation or changing the bitness, but you may be able to tweak the Lua code to produce the code you need. Here is the [maillist thread](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2016-02/msg00176.html) for Lua 5.1 that recommends using `#define LUAC_STR_SIZE_TYPE int`.

If this doesn't work, you may be able to change `ldump.c` to produce 32-bit compatible code. The source code has the following comment (5.4): `All high-level dumps go through dumpVector; you can change it to change the endianness of the result`. You may be able to update it to change bitness by changing handling of `DIBS`, `dumpSize`, and several other places.